# JS. Добавление объекта в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, json

Есть функция

```
    function saveslogan(){
        var slogan = document.querySelectorAll('.slogan');
        var obj = [];

        slogan.forEach(element =>

///Вот тут что-то делать надо
            obj.push(element.name , element.value)
            

         );

        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
```

Который засовывает в массив:

["Название","Значение","Название","Значение","Название","Значение"]

Вместо этого пытаюсь использовать двумерный массив, для результата:

[{"Название":"Значение"},{"Название":"Значение"},{"Название":"Значение"}]

Но с этим проблемы

Comment: `obj.push({element.name: element.value})`

Comment: obj.push({element.name: element.value})

Comment: Кажется, скорее так: `obj.push({ [element.name]: element.value })`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function saveslogan(){
        var slogan = document.querySelectorAll('.slogan');
        var obj = [];

        slogan.forEach(element =>

///Вот тут что-то делать надо
            obj.push({[element.name] : element.value})
            

         );

        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
    }
```

Comment: Кажется, скорее так: `obj.push({ [element.name]: element.value })`, иначе будет SyntaxError.

Comment: Да ошибся, уже поправил